# Trying to use a where statement in cursor creation (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a block that accepts input from a prompt and uses that input to filter the result set for the cursor. Keep in mind I'm a novice here so I maybe making a very routine mistake, and thank you for your help. My current code is below.

```
Set serveroutput on

DECLARE
  ACCEPT a PROMPT  “Please Enter a Date,  eg. Format -  01 or 30"

  datev char
  datev := &a;

  CURSOR cur_day_cursor IS
    SELECT Arrival_Date Adate
      FROM FLIGHT
      WHERE TO_CHAR(Arrival_Date, ‘DD’) = datev;

  cur_day_cursor_var cur_day_cursor%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN Cur_day_cursor;

  LOOP
    Fetch Cur_day_cursor
      INTO cur_day_cursor_var;
    EXIT WHEN cur_day_cursor%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (cur_day_cursor_var.Adate);
  END LOOP;

  IF cur_day_cursor%ISOPEN THEN
    CLOSE cur_day_cursor;
  END IF;
END;
```

The where statement is causing my errors, so I was thinking that I may have to let the cursor collect all the data and then filter it when displaying, but I'm not sure if I can even do that.

The error I keep receiving ERROR at line 9:- 
ORA-06550: line 9, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHERE" when expecting one of the following:
begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
 current cursor delete
exists prior

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why Oracle is reporting the error at the `WHERE`.  Sometimes the parser gets pretty confused by bad syntax and doesn't point to the real problem.  You have several syntax errors before the cursor definition.

`ACCEPT` is a SQLPlus command, not a PL/SQL statement.  Move your `ACCEPT` line above the `DECLARE`.

Also, your variable declaration and initialization are incorrect.  The assignment should be part of the declaration line; you need to provide a length for the `CHAR` datatype; and the substitution value should be in quotes to be treated as a string.  A valid version of your lines would be:

```
datev  char(2) := '&a';
```

Comment: Sorry, the "ACCEPT a PROMPT  “Please Enter a Date,  eg. Format -  01 or 30" Part of the code, was placed before the Declare section in my initial code. I was just messing around with certain things in attempt to get the code to run.

I've tried the suggested solution, but i'm running into a problem where the script hangs right after entering the prompted variable (datev) 
Screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/kFCsV5Z.jpg

Comment: Your posted code does not have a slash following the PL/SQL block, which is required to actually execute it.  So it might just be that SQLPlus is waiting for more input.  Add a `/` on a line by itself following the final `END;`.  Another possibility is simply that the query driving the loop is taking a very long time to execute, but I think that's doubtful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem is that the single-quotes around `‘DD’` aren't single-quotes. It looks like the code was created in an editor which changes apostrophes into those special "look kind of like single quotes but aren't really" characters. Replace the original version of the WHERE clause with the following:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(Arrival_Date, 'DD') = datev;
```

and I suspect you'll be fine.

And get yourself a good code editor.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same query as above, and got the results perfectly fine.
You have few syntax as well as logical error which I corrected in your query. The syntax error(s) are -

```
datev char
datev := &a;
```

You can't do such an initialization in PL/SQL. You probably have to complete it in a single line like below -

```
datev char := &a;
```

The logical mistake(s) are -

1. Why use a CHAR variable to store data when you know that the value being returned is NUMBER.
2. You expect numbers from 1-31; then why do you choose the default size of char which as 1. It will fail if you provide a 2-digit number
3. Even if you increase the size of CHAR to CHAR(2), you will not get results when the users enters  a number like 1 or 01, because for character wise comparison, '1' != '1 '(Mark the extra space at the end, because of char(2)); and also '1' != '01'.
   The only solution for above is to use a NUMBER datatype.

Now here I am posting my query which is similar to your query, with a change of column name and table name. Please replace with your required names and try -
(Take care not to execute the ACCEPT....) with the PL/SQL block. It should be done in the SQL prompt first and then the other DECLARE section should be run.

```
--ACCEPT a NUMBER PROMPT  'Please Enter a Date,  eg. Format -  01 or 30 :'
--Run the above line first in SQL Prompt and then execute the rest as whole
DECLARE
  datev NUMBER(2) := &a;
  CURSOR cur_day_cursor IS
    SELECT Ename, HireDate Adate
      FROM Emp
      WHERE TO_CHAR(HireDate, 'D') = datev;
  cur_day_cursor_var cur_day_cursor%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN Cur_day_cursor;
  LOOP
    Fetch Cur_day_cursor
      INTO cur_day_cursor_var;
    EXIT WHEN cur_day_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (cur_day_cursor_var.Adate);
  END LOOP;
  IF cur_day_cursor%ISOPEN THEN
    CLOSE cur_day_cursor;
  END IF;
END;
/
```